# Constructing overriding using HTML markup?

Tags: html

I have a link and if a user clicks it this is what I need to happen: after downloading i need to override the security pop up question that asks whether or not to run the file.

Is this possible?

Comment: This is a security measure. If you could override it in HTML it would be useless.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. If it was, it would be simple for attackers to tell their downloads not to display the security popup, making the security popup useless.